# ¿Ayuda no puedo cambiar de idioma en Django?

Tags: django, internacionalización

Estoy tratando de crear una pagina en la cual se pueda cambiar de idioma a través de un select, seguí un tutorial y justo cuando creí que lo había logrado, me doy cuenta de que al hacer el post no sucede nada.

Esto es lo que tengo en settings.py:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'languages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'curriculum.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'curriculum.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/


LANGUAGES = (
 ('es', _('Espanish')),
 ('en', _('English')),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

EL proyecto se llama curriculum y contiene esto en urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('languages.urls')),

    path('languages/', include('languages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Y tengo una app llamada languages la cual en urls.py contiene:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

Finalmente en templates está este código:

```
{% load i18n %}
<h1>{% blocktrans %}Hola{% endblocktrans %}</h1>
<p>{% blocktrans %}Bienvenido al sitio{% endblocktrans %}</p>
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ lang.1 }} ({{ lang.0 }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Mi archivo locale se encuentra dentro de la app pero ya probé poniéndolo junto con manage.py

Comment: Has editado los archivos .po de locale para que haga la traducción?

Comment: Gracias, pero se me escapaba algo, decidi cambiar el idioma en settings y vi que si se hacian los cambios, asi que revise el codigo para cambiar el idioma atra ves de un select y ahora funciona

Comment: Genial! me alegro que lo solucionaras